# Flask - simple delete of database entry - missing positional argument

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I’m new to flask, I am just trying to get a simple delete request to remove a database entry.

html table

```
...
{% for l in logbook %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ l.TO_UTC }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.LDG_UTC }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.dep_airport }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.arr_airport }}</td>
    <td><a href="{{ url_for('logbookdelete',id_del=l.id ) }}">Delete {{ l.id }}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

[image]

the id_del refers to the delete app route:

```
@app.route('/logbook/delete')
def logbookdelete(id_del):
    delete = Logbook.query.filter_by(id=id_del).first()
    db.session.delete(delete)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('logbook'))
```

Current error: `TypeError: logbookdelete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id_del'`

How do I get the `{{ l.id }}` to be used as the `id_del` in the app route?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<id_del>` in route.

```
@app.route('/logbook/delete/<id_del>')
def logbookdelete(id_del):
    delete = Logbook.query.filter_by(id=id_del).first()
    db.session.delete(delete)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('logbook'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple I was missing!